# dataTables AngularJS options sort

Tags: angularjs, datatables

Here is my table : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzjPro
I wan't to sort only first 2 columns, the column `Position` was not sortable.

Code :

```
$scope.dataTableOpt = {

  "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100,-1], [10, 50, 100,'All']],
  "aoSearchCols": [
      null
    ],
  };
```

This doesn't work :

```
 $scope.dataTableOpt = {

      "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100,-1], [10, 50, 100,'All']],
      "aoSearchCols": [
          null
        ],
      "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "aDataSort": [ 0,1 ], "aTargets": [ 0,1 ] }
        ],
      };
```

Thanks for answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you have picked up some sunsetted legacy code. Use `columnDefs` and [**`orderable`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable) instead :

```
$scope.dataTableOpt = {
  lengthMenu: [[10, 50, 100,-1], [10, 50, 100,'All']],
  columnDefs: [
    { targets: 2, orderable: false }
  ]
};
```

`targets` is the zero based column index. It can be an array of indexes.

Also take a look at [**angular datatables directives**](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome). You may face problems with rendering and so on, if you use "pure" jQuery datatables along with angular.